# Get the contents of a folder in Azure Blob Store

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How can I list the contents of a folder in the Azure Blob Store?

I am able to list the contents of a container using the below method.

```
public void listBlobsInContainer()
    {
     // Loop over blobs within the container and output the URI to each of them.
        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : blobContainer.listBlobs()) {
           System.out.println(blobItem.getUri());
       }
    }
```

However, this only gives me the top level contents. I would like to get the contents of a folder inside one of the blobs listed above.

For my below Azure storage, say, the above method returns output as 6970b2a5-e220-4d68-8fc0-2992a1b8bdb7 and 83755a8a-b39a-4069-a64e-9c08fa8a39e5, which are the contents of the container called `datafileuploads`
[image]

However, I would like to get the contents of the folder, `6970b2a5-e220-4d68-8fc0-2992a1b8bdb7`